# Getting "connection was reset" when uploading large files using the file upload control

Tags: xpages

When I'm trying to upload large files (>10Mb) with a file upload control in my XPages application, I'm always redirected to an error page in my browser, saying "**The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading**". In the application's xsp.properties file I already set "**xsp.upload.maximumsize**=128000" which should allow uploads of files with up to 128Mb. However I keep getting the "connection was reset" error. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to xsp.upload.maximumsize setting you have to set values in Domino Directory in **server document** in "Internet Protocols..." tab:

Set fields

- "HTTP" tab / "HTTP Protocol Limits" section / "**Maximum size of request content**" and
- "Domino Web Engine" tab / "POST Data" section / "**Maximum POST data**"

to value 128000 too.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was exactly what I have been searching for. It works perfectly now!