# video player stops working on xPage after 2 minutes

Tags: html, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a simple video player on my xPage that refers to an attached video in Notes document.

```
<video class="videoContainer" controls="controls" id="callVideo" preload="none">
    <source src="./xxxxxxxxxxxx/$file/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>

//Video format mp4
//Video length ~55min
//File size ~50Mb
```

it works fine if I open the page from one server but stops to reproduce video if I open it from another server. It stops after about 2-3 minutes. So is it something I need to tuneup on Domino server itself?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24321381/2065611 . Maybe one of the settings is too small for your second server.

Comment: This is another (heplful) link: http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2014/maximum-file-upload-size-in-domino-all-the-places-to-edit

Comment: Can you open the video directly by opening the video url in the browser or a video client (VLC / Windows Media Player)?

Comment: yes I can open that video through browser or download it. It's not corrupted. And these options are the same on both servers: 1. "HTTP" tab / "HTTP Protocol Limits" section / "Maximum size of request content" and 2. "Domino Web Engine" tab / "POST Data" section / "Maximum POST data". Just 10000. But I'll increase it on another one and check

Comment: What does the browser debugger shows you in the network tab when the video freezes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it's not a problem uploading the video to Domino but streaming it from Domino.

It's worth checking the Notes log for any Java memory errors. The video will be being streamed from the server to the browser via Java, so it seems hypothetically plausible that one server could be hitting Java memory heap errors where another is not. The `HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize` is set independently on servers so may be different.

Comment: You are right. There are a lot of such errors: 
1. HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't get a Writer while an OutputStream is already in use
2. HTTP JVM: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

I'll ask our Domino admins to play with HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize and see what's happen

Comment: You could also access the attachment directly with „?OpenAttachment“.

Comment: Increasing heap size may not be a complete solution. A 55 minute video streamed may then work for one user, but may cause problems if two try to view it simultaneously, not sure. Sven's suggestion of download and view is best. If streaming is required, different recording tools result in different-sized videos, editing tools can also reduce the size. It's best to ensure it's as small as possible for the appropriate performance. Alternatively, host it on a dedicated video-streaming service. If the answer was right, please also mark it correct